# Hibernate 6.x: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.langString

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus-panache

Consider the following table with a column defined as

```
TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_CODE  VARCHAR2(1)
```

And this is the field in the entity:

```
@Column(name = "TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_CODE", length = 1)
private String transactionCategoryCode;
```

This setup has worked well until now that I want to migrate to Hibernate version 6.x. Now, whenever data is accessed from the table the following exception is thrown:

```
class java.lang.Character cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Character and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I immagine this is due to Hibernate interpreting one char columns as `Character` and not as `String` by default. How can Hibernate be forced to interprete this column as `String`?

Comment: Why? A char is almost certainly more efficient. Also, why not store it as a `CHAR(1)`? What is the point of a variable length character field of one character?

Comment: I agree a char is more efficient. But if I definitely want to keep the column type as is, how can this be done?